# Cargar un select mediante ajax, json y php

Tags: php, ajax, json

Llevo todo el fin de semana liada con este problema. Tengo un index con un select al que lo intento cargar con datos de mi base de datos.
El caso que eso mismo lo he hecho con otros select en otros index de mi aplicación pero no sé por que el de comidas nunca me lo carga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En ese me cargar un select pero el de Comidas no, y estoy haciendo otro index distinto solo con comidas pero nada, no me carga.

Os dejo mi código por si me podéis ayudar.

borrarComida.html

```
<form action="" name="frmBorrarComida" class="form-horizontal" id="frmBorrarComida">
    <legend class=" rounded bg-dark text-white" style="text-align:center;">Borrar Comida
    </legend>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="selectComida">Comidas:</label>
            <select name="selectComida" id="selectComida"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="borrarComida" name="borrarComida" value="Borrar" />
</form>
```

borrarComida.js

```
//# sourceURL=altaDieta.js;

$("#borrarComida").click(fBorrarComida);
cargarDesplegableComidas();

    function cargarDesplegableComidas() {
 $.ajax({
            url: "Comida/getComidas.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: true, // por defecto
            method: "GET",
            success: procesarGetComidas
        });
    }
    function procesarGetComidas(oDatos) {
        var sOptions = "";
    
        for (var i = 0; i < oDatos.length; i++) {
    
            sOptions += '<option value="' + oDatos[i].comida + '">';
            sOptions += oDatos[i].nombre;
            sOptions += '</option>';
        }
        }
    
        $("#selectComida").html(sOptions);
    }
    

function fBorrarComida() {

    let oComida = {
        id_comida: frmBorrarComida.selectComida.value.trim(),

    };
      //let sParametros = "datos=" + JSON.stringify(oComida);
      $.post("Comida/borrarComida.php", oComida, respuestaBorrarComida, 'json');
    
        function respuestaBorrarComida(oDatos, sStatus, oXHR)
        {
            if(oDatos.error){
                alert(oDatos.mensaje);
            }else{
                alert(oDatos.mensaje);
                frmBorrarComida.reset();
                $("#frmBorrarComida").parent().hide("normal");
            }
        }
      
    }
   

    function instanciarXHR() {
        var xhttp = null;
    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else // code for IE5 and IE6
        {
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    
        return xhttp;
    }
```

getComidas.php

```
<?php

// Configuración BASE DE DATOS MYSQL
$servidor  = "localhost";
$basedatos = "nutrilife";
$usuario   = "root";
$password  = "";

// Creamos la conexión al servidor.
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password,$basedatos) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");

// Consulta SQL para obtener los datos de los comidas.
$sql = "select * from comidas";
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

$datos = [];

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
    // Almacenamos en un array cada una de las filas que vamos leyendo del recordset.
    $datos[] = $fila;
}

// función de PHP que convierte a formato JSON el array.
echo json_encode($datos); 

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Mi base de datos en la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te estás liando con esto: `success: procesarGetComidas`, haciéndolo así, la función `procesarGetComidas` no reconocerá jamás los datos que fueron traídos del servidor, ¿por qué no usas la forma habitual?: `success: function(data) {  //manejar aquí la respuesta que estaría en data o pasar data a otra función si quisieras 
      }` Puedes ver [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5316697/5587982) y sus respuestas para entender mejor la manera de pasar los datos a otra parte fuera del contexto del `success`  en caso de que sea necesario hacerlo.

Comment: Otra cosa que se observa es que el parámetro en la función se llama `oDatos2` pero en el interior de la misma intentas buscar `oDatos`...

Comment: Gracias, mirare la pregunta que me dejas. Lo raro que he realizado otros igual utlizando esa forma y si funcionan. lo de oDatos2 se me coló porque probé a cambiar algunas variables. ahora lo corrijo para que no haya confusiones.

Comment: Otra cosa fundamental cuando algo no funciona es **depurar**, así vas determinando con más facilidad dónde está el fallo. Por ejemplo, puedes poner un `console.log(oDatos);` y revisar la consola para ver si está trayendo datos o no, así no estarás trabajando ciegamente. Si en la consola no muestra nada sabrás que el fallo está en el servidor. De todos modos, dado que las llamadas Ajax son asíncronas, para menos complicación es recomendable manejar la respuesta dentro del `success` y si la mandas fuera, tienes que saber cómo hacerlo, pues en algunos contextos te podría dar problemas.

Comment: Probaste de generar el select con jquery, en vez de hacerlo concatenando strings?

Comment: Otra cosa más: en las llamadas Ajax que esperan datos del tipo JSON el código de servidor (PHP) tiene que ser **coherente** con el tipo de respuesta esperado. En tu PHP resuelves los fallos con un simple y horrible `die`, si el código falla, tu petición Ajax no recibirá un JSON, que es lo que espera siempre. Para dar coherencia, tienes que controlar los errores, evitando `die`, y metiéndolos por ejemplo en un array con una clave `error`, así en el `success` podrás verificar con algo así más o menos: `if (oDatos.error) { //hubo error }else{//no hubo error, mostrar los option}`

Comment: @FedericoSaenz el `select`ya está definido en el HTML: `<select name="selectComida" id="selectComida"></select>` y luego mediante este código: `$("#selectComida").html(sOptions);` se le agregarían los `option` que son recogidos dentro del bucle `for`. El problema creo que está en la forma de manejar el `success` o bien en el servidor. Hay que depurar en varios puntos hasta ver dónde está fallando.